# Unordered_map produce secondary key

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I'm using strings as a type of key for my `unordered_map` but is it possible that I could associate a secondary unique key, *independent* from the primary, so I could perform a find operation with the second key?

I was thinking that the key could be a hash number the internal hash algorithm came up with.

I thought of including an id (increasing by 1 each time) to the structure I'm saving but then again, I would have to look up for the key that is a string first.

Reason behind this: I want to make lists that enlist some of the elements in the `unordered_map` but saving strings in the list is very inefficient instead of saving `int` or `long long`. (I would prefer not to use pointers but rather a bookkeeping style of procedure).

Comment: A second map that is mapping the secondary key to the primary key?

Comment: Values need to maintain a strict order based on their key. This would be challenging with two independent keys per value. You likely want to keep two `unordered_map`s.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude both keys independently should be able to find the same entry. Another idea I had was to use an array to store the corresponding string to the array slot with the index I'm looking for, that is if I create my own id numbers in a consecutive order starting form 0.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: "Independent from the primary"

Comment: You could store a `shared_ptr` and just directly access the pointee from either container, but this will all depend very much on your specific requirements. Like it might be too heavy if your container is huge

Comment: [boost::multi_index_container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't use a hash number the internal hash algorithm came up with because it could change the numbers due to the table growth in size. This is called rehashing. Also hashes are not guaranteed to be unique (they certainly won't be).

Keeping pointers to elements in your list will work just fine, since `unordered_map` doesn't invalidate pointers. But the deletion of the elements will be hard.

Boost has [`multi_index_container`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), which provides many useful database-like functions. It will be perfect for your task.

If you don't want to use Boost, you could use `unordered_map` with unique integer indices, and another `unordered_map` which keeps `string->index` pairs for searching by string keys. The deletion will also be hard, because either you will check all your lists each time you delete a record, or you will check if the record still exists each time you are traversing the list.

Comment: I second the use of `boost::multi_index_container`.  Specifically, it manages all of the indices for you, so if you insert with one,  the items is indexed in all others.  Similarly for deletion.  It is also possible to get from an iterator to one index to an integrator to any other in `O(1)`.